# How to use registered, trademark or special symbols (other than Greek alphabets) in R, especially in plot headings?

Tags: r, special-characters

I am trying to use the  registered, trademark symbols in one of my R graphs. Is there are a way to present these special characters via codes or other identifiers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just include them in the string. You can either put the actual character in the string or use the unicode escape

```
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol=2))
plot(1,1,main="Registered®")
plot(1,1,main="Registered\U00AE")
plot(1,1,main="TradeMark™")
plot(1,1,main="TradeMark\U2122")
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it. BTW you can look up codes http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/